# Does burning an  ISO file on a non-rewritable DVD make the DVD read-only?

Tags: iso-image, dvd-burning, read-only

If I burn an ISO file on a non-rewritable DVD, does the DVD become read-only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends what kind of DVD you are using, if its a rewritable you can always write something else on it, otherwise it is read-only.

Comment: But I think that non-rewritable DVDs can be written several times until it is full.

Comment: That depends if you finalize or not the DVD when you write on it. When burning an ISO the settings are usually set to finalize the DVD (not allowing anything else to be added to it). Some burning programs might allow you to change that.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. However, you can leave a DVD open for data to be added. I believe it's called a multi-session DVD.